# Populating and clearing an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Swift array of custom objects, which I'd like to repeatedly populate and clear. Something like this:

```
var myArray:[[CustomClass]]=[[CustomClass]]()
myArray[0][0]=firstItem
myArray[1][5]=secondItem

// Later...
myArray=[[CustomClass]]()
myArray[2][3]=firstItem
myArray[0][0]=secondItem
```

Everything I'm trying seems to be giving "array index out of range" errors. What's the right way to do this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: In your example, you're accessing (empty) arrays by subscript. This results in "array index out of range" because it's... empty. If you want to add something to an array you can use either `append()` or `+= [CustomClass]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an item to your [array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) like this. You need to use the append method.

```
var myArr:[[Int]]=[]

myArr.append([0,1,2])
myArr.append([3,4,5])
myArr.append([6,7,8])


println(myArr)  // "[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]"
println(myArr[2][2]) // 8
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

> You can use subscript syntax to change an existing value at a given index

```
shoppingList[0] = "Six eggs"
```

> You can also use subscript syntax to change a range of values at once

```
shoppingList[4...6] = ["Bananas", "Apples"]
```

But to add new elements to the array you'll need to use `append`

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically create array indexes by accessing them, you need to specifically create the storage in the array.

```
var matrix = [[CustomClass]](count: 10, repeatedValue: [])
```

But that only allocates 1 dimension of the matrix. The `repeatedValue` needs to be an array of CustomClass.

```
var row = [CustomClass](count: 10, repeatedValue: CustomClass())
```

Putting that all together, you get the final initializer for a 10x10 matrix using default values for each element.

```
var matrix = [[CustomClass]](count: 10, repeatedValue: [CustomClass](count: 10, repeatedValue: CustomClass()))
```

If you don't have a good default value for your CustomClass, then you will need the matrix to hold an optional.

```
var matrix = [[CustomClass?]](count: 10, repeatedValue: [CustomClass?](count: 10, repeatedValue: nil))
```